# Optimal query to PostgreSQL and complex index on 3 columns, when 2 columns have static values and 3-rd one uses operator IN

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, indexing

There's a table with compound index (col1, col2, col3). There's a lot of data in this table.
Want to build query for example WHERE col1 = 2 AND col2 = 12 AND col3 IN (1, 2, 3, ..., 40)
Is there a way to use index fully (with 3 columns)?

When I'm trying

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.col1 = 2
    AND t.col2 = 12
    AND t.col3 IN (1, 2, 3, ..., 40)
```

Postgres planner makes index scan on (col1, col2) and then uses SeqScan to filter one by one 400k of rows with `col3 IN (1, 2, 3, ..., 40)`

If I try

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE (col1, col2, col3) IN VALUES (2, 12, 1), (2, 12, 2), (2, 12, 3), ... ,(2, 12, 40)
```

it gives error:

> temporary file size exceeds temp_file_limit

So it works slow. Is there a way to make postgres use somehow compound index for 3 columns?

Comment: The index scan on `(col1, col2)` may be the best you can do.  The `IN` clause is difficult to optimize.

Comment: What happens to the execution plan if you put the `values` part in a CTE and then `join cte c on (t.col1, t.col2, t.col3) = (c.col1, c.col2, c.col3)`?

Comment: could you please share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) for this statement? (in plain text, as an update to your original question) And the DDL for all tables and indexes involved, also in plain text.

Comment: @MikeOrganek It seems like you're right -- everything works perfectly fine with CTE
I will test in on logs, and if it works as it should Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Please show us the plan itself.  Your description of the plan doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, it looks like we can force use of the index through an explicit join on `(col1, col2, col3) = (arg1, arg2, arg3)`.

I don't know how you are calling this query, but if called from a host language that allows passing an `int[]` type through the database driver, my query would look like this:

```
with invars as (
  select 2 as c1val, 12 as c2val,
         array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 40] as c3vals  
), search_tuples as (
  select i.c1val, i.c2val, u.c3val
    from invars i
         cross join lateral unnest(i.c3vals) as u(c3val)
)
select t.*
  from search_tuples s
       join table1 t 
    on (t.col1, t.col2, t.col3) = (s.c1val, s.c2val, s.c3val);
```

[A working fiddle with random test records and `explain`](https://dbfiddle.uk/O-ct6uAF)

Comment: But if you just run his initial query in your fiddle, it also uses the index.

Comment: @jjanes question was about my case with a lot of data
Based on how statistic works for my case, original queries worked as I described
I can't share sensitive details, but trust me --  Mike's approach works

Comment: The only point - I don't understand why do we need `cross join lateral` (especially `lateral`) if it works that way?
`with cte as (select 2 as c1val, 12 as c2val, unnest(array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 40]) as c3vals )`

Comment: @UladzislauVasiliuk  it is just a matter of preference.  Using UNNEST (and other set-returning functions) in the select list is often frowned upon as fragile and confusing.  There are many other ways to express the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading the `col3` possible values into a bona fide table and then rewriting the query to the following:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE t1.col1 = 2 AND
      t1.col2 = 12 AND
      EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM table2 t2
          WHERE t2.col3 = t1.col3
      );
```

This assumes that `table2` has the following structure:

```
table2:
col3
1
2
3
...
40
```

`table1` might be able to use an index on `(col1, col2, col3)`.  An index should also be placed on `table2 (col3)`, to ensure rapid lookups.